# Offline installation of Python setuptools_scm in python 2.7

Tags: python, package-management

I'm new to Python and we have an installation of Python 2.7 on our Unix server. Our server doesn't have access to the internet and I need to install some modules not already in the Python standard library without using the internet.

I've managed to do this for a couple of modules after downloading the source files and running the command `/usr/bin/env python2.7 setup.py install --user`. However, when I do this for setuptools_scm I get the following output:

> $ /usr/bin/env python2.7 setup.py install --user
>   /u00/home/user/wr/scripts/setuptools_scm-master/src/setuptools_scm/utils.py:119: UserWarning: 'git' was not found
>     warnings.warn("%r was not found" % name)
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>    File "setup.py", line 117, in 
>      arguments.update(scm_config())
>    File "setup.py", line 46, in scm_config
>      return dict(version=get_version(root=here, parse=parse, **config))
>    File "/u00/home/user/wr/scripts/setuptools_scm-master/src/setuptools_scm/**init**.py", line 15, in get_version
>      parsed_version = _do_parse(config)
>    File "/u00/home/user/wr/scripts/setuptools_scm-master/src/setuptools_scm/**init**.py", line 11, in _do_parse
>      "use git+https://github.com/user/proj.git#egg=proj" % config.absolute_root
>   LookupError: setuptools-scm was unable to detect version for '/u00/home/user/wr/scripts/setuptools_scm-master'.

Am I missing some sort of dependency, doing something else wrong, or will it just not work without connecting to the internet?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the binary `git`.  There should be a package for your Unix variant in your repository, read its name and how to install it here: https://git-scm.com/download/linux

Tip: If you are using RedHat Enterprise 7, then you can enable Software Collections to get a recent version:

```sh
yum-config-manager --enable rhel-server-rhscl-7-rpms
yum install -y rh-git29
```